# designing classes based on database-design

Tags: database-design, class-design, entities

i have a little problem with my ojt-project. i was given a database design and have to do a class design for it. however i have never designed classes based on an exisiting database so i am confused of which classes i should design.

here's a little explanation of what is going on:

entities in db: applicant, application, skill, offer, customer.

a customer (company a) sends in an inquiry to company b (where i do my ojt). company b has an applicants pool where all applications from people who seek jobs from them go. they then search for a fitting applicant based on skills needed from company a. if a match is made and company a is happy with the customer, then he gets a job. if not, he is put back into the pool with status on-hold.

so bascially i thought of just designing the classes 1 to 1 based on the database design. of course the entities i described here are only a small part of the whole database. but those entities are the ones i would also design into a class. like an applicant can also send in documents. the documents are stored on a file server and links to them are stored in the database. this document entity is something i would not design into a class since it makes no sense, the file is just uploaded and its properties are stored into the database.

am i going into the right direction here with my thinking? i would be very thankful for some infos or corrections...

Comment: Why the german title? I would translate but Google Translate doesn't offer many good suggestions

Comment: lol, sorry for that. corrected and thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

One class per table is a reasonable place to start, especially if your tables are already in third normal form.  However there are lots of places where you might vary from this.  For example, pure associative entities don't necessarily require a class, depending on how you plan to model the relationships between tables.

There are various existing ORM Frameworks that do this sort of thing for you.  You should consider using one of these ORM Frameworks rather than starting off from a blank page.  These frameworks handle *a lot* of repetitive drudgery and let you focus on application logic instead of data access logic.

Comment: yes this is what i thought. i am still in planning phase so i dont need to define class properties yet. i just need to define class relationships for now so this will be sufficient. maybe i will look into this when i have the proper software installed, for now my laptop only contains programs for planning the project.